# Isekai manga with a female protagonist getting reincarnated after being pushed off a cliff, gets a peacock

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

- The protagonist gets pushed down a cliff by someone who is romantically interested in her second account which is the strongest person in the whole game which causes her to get reincarnated
- She ends up getting a bird who eats a bunch of magic herbs and ends up actually being the last of a tribe of peacocks and one of the peacocks ruled the world at one point
- she also is a potionmaker and one of the best in the new world

Answer (score 3):

*Feng Qi Cang Lan*, a 2013 manhwa.

From [TimelessLeaf](https://timelessleaf.com/feng-qi-cang-lan-2/):

> **XiaoWan the best player of the virtual reality game Cang Lan, gets pushed off a cliff by an evil wretch.** Instead of dying, she ends up in another world where martial arts and spiritual essence determines one’s fate. XiaoWan who was deemed useless by all of the people in this world will not take her destiny as it is! Will she be able to become the best in this world as well? We will see!

There's your "last peacock of its clan" bit (from a fan translation of chapter 75.5):

[image: Female character finds a peacock feather and deduces all members of the Peacock Clan are not dead]

---

Found with the Google query `isekai manga "pushed * cliff"`, the third page of results returned a preview of [this website](http://jali.at/3kqkuxhwi/chinese-manhua-raws.html) (apparently now dead), which contained the same text as above.

Comment: If this is the right answer, you cna accept it by clicking the chekmark on the left.